# tagging files for filtering

Tags: files, search

I am new to emacs and I been trying to find how to tag multiple files with multiple tags and then filter or search based on the tags. If you are familiar with the way tags work in Evernote or TagSpaces that is pretty much the same idea.

is it possible to do that with emacs?

PS: I was reading about ctag and etag but those look more to be specific to code tags and for navigation within files instead.

Comment: Is this about tagging `org-mode` files, or all files generally?

Comment: it's about files in a specific folder, which I'm currently used neo-tree to navigate from file to file within emacs. PS: I will always have the same top directory (i.e. `~/home/notes`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then yes, you can do this easily. Tagging *files* using Bookmark+ means creating [*autofile bookmarks*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutofileBookmarks) for the files and then adding [tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) for those bookmarks.

You can think of an autofile bookmark as just a file wrapper: a way to attach meta information (such as tags) to a file. But you can use an autofile bookmark much as you would use a file.

You can then search, or filter bookmarks (or just autofile bookmarks) in several ways. For autofile bookmarks, this means you can search, filter, or query-replace the files.

Comment: thanks! Looks like it's exactly what I was looking for! I'll give it a try and report back!

Answer (score 0):

If you are maintaining a directory of lots of text (or org, markdown, etc) files you could try out [deft](http://jblevins.org/projects/deft/). This mode provides dynamic filtering of your set of notes, making it easy to find (or save) a specific bit of text, without having to tag everything.